# Porting my website from managed hosting to Scaleway VPS

Tags: web-hosting, vps, cloudflare

I have decided to port my website from managed hosting to VPS as I need access to full functionality of linux to install different packages (I want to publish versions of my website developed with different web frameworks).

Currently, my configuration is as follows:

- domain registrar is Georgian Research and Educational Networks Association (GRENA, grena.ge) that points to Cloudflare NS servers
- hosting is ProServ (proserv.ge) with cPanel and corresponding default DNS configuration (I mean A, AAAA, CNAME etc records) that was done by ProServ support team when setting up the hosting
- Cloudflare account that currently points to ProServ servers

Is there any guide available on how to tie Scaleway server with Cloudflare?

Is just changing the IP address to Scaleway server in DNS records enough to set it up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty of moving hosts I find drastically depends on the site/content you are moving. Moving a static website is relatively easy compared to moving something larger such as some kind of CMS or forum which uses a database etc...

From what you have said it sounds like the cPanel DNS configuration isn't actually doing anything right now anyway. cPanel automatically creates DNS records for ease of access to the end user as it is expecting the user to be using cPanel as the nameservers. But in your case your domains nameservers are set to Cloudflare so the actual cPanel DNS isnt even being used by the domain.

> Is just changing the IP address to Scaleway server in DNS records enough to set it up?

At the most basic level yes. If you log into the Cloudflare dashboard and change your A record from the Shared hosting providers IP address to the VPSs IP address then yes the domain will then be pointed to the VPS. However just because the domain is pointed to the VPS doesn't necessarily mean everything will instantly start to work. There has to be a web server (such as Apache, nginx, etc) setup and running on the VPS in order to actually serve web requests.

Generally you need to do the following however note that this is massively simplified and the complexity of each task will largly depend on the site you are moving and your own end goals:

1. Setup the VPS (Install and configure a web server in order to serve requests)
2. Copy over all your files from your shared hosting web root to your VPS web root
3. Change the DNS records in cloudflare to point to your VPS

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a good answer! To be honest, while waiting for it, I did come to the same conclusion. I did succeed in installing all the necessary packages, and even configuring Apache with SSL/TLS certificate (which I've never done before). I also installed webmin as an alternative to cPanel Luckily, the main content of my website is just a static page, which I did copy over. The rest is WordPress blog with just two posts, but that's a challenge for another day. Thank you again for the answer, though! It's good to get a confirmation that my way of thinking was correct